# Trying to to work on machine learning algorithm KNN but everytime its not getting the right result instead just showing what is present in last column

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, prediction, knn

I am working on my machine learning code which uses KNN to predict the genera of book on the basis of age, but the problem is that it only taking last value from the column and just showing the same result all the time. Can anyone help me resolve this issue. Gender is just optional main work is just with age and genera.

Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Book.csv')

X = data.drop(columns=['Genera'])
Y = data['Genera']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
predict = classifier.predict([[21,1]])
print(predict)
```

Below is the link of picture of my dummy data from csv file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIArY.png)

Comment: Why should the same code with the same data show different results each time it is used?

Comment: In the second last line "predict = classifier.predict([[21,1]])", what ever age I enter its showing the same result, if I change 21 which is age to 30 , it shows same result

Comment: maybe both 21 and 30 are in the same group - did you check for other values? OR maybe it uses different data then you expect. You could add example data (as text, not image) in code so we could test it.

Comment: to make code more readable you should put all `import` at the beginning

Comment: what result do you get? What result do you expected?

Comment: or maybe you need more data with more parameters. Using only `Age` to predict anything may not be enough.

Comment: Tried with more data and one more parameter, now its giving me different results. It helped. May be the problem was that I was using way less data to predict the result

Answer (score 0):

1. Visualize your data with output label it's help you identify what's going
   wrong. sometimes ml model perform worst when we have messy data or lack
   of features.
2. Try to fit model without standard scaling data sometimes scaling compress
   our variability and our ml model enable to classify original things.
3. use classification report.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   data = pd.read_csv('Book.csv')

   X = data.drop(columns=['Genera'])
   Y = data['Genera']
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)

   from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
   classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
   classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
   predict = classifier.predict([[21,1]])
   print(predict)
   ```